# Chrome extension not saving to local storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension is not saving an string into local storage, can you guys check what i'm doing wrong?

I'm trying  to save the data that was copied from the selected text. I can select and show that in the popup but can't save. I want to be able to save so I can have the popup back to it's state when it's open again.

Manifest

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "test ",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png",
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "contextMenus",
      "storage"
   ]
}
```

Popup html, pretty basic

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <button id="test">Test</button>

        <div id="title"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Popup js

```
window.onload = function() {
    chrome.storage.local.get('value', function(result) {
        document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = result;
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const test = document.querySelector('#test');
    test.addEventListener('click', function() {
        chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, (tabs) => {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, { code: `document.getSelection().toString()` }, (result) => {

                document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = result;

                chrome.storage.local.set({value: result}, function() {
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `result` is an object that has as properties all the keys you've requested, in this case, you've requested just one key (`value`) so you need to use `result.value` instead of just `result`

Comment: If my explanation doesn't make sense, you can find a better one in the [documentation for `StorageArea`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/#type-StorageArea)